# How to remove the button click highlight

Tags: button, xamarin.forms

I have a submit button in my page, when I click on the button, button color is slightly changing (highlight).

How to remove this highlight feature in xamarin forms.

Comment: Alternatively, use a BoxView with [TapGesture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap)

Comment: @Aswathy I find one thread about talking [Button background without a ripple effect on Android](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9984), you can take a look.

Comment: You can use Label with gesture recognizer if you want to save your time,

Answer (score 1):

On Android it is called ripple effect, you can create a custom renderer to hide it

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Button), typeof(MyButtonRenderer))]

namespace App.Droid
{
    public class MyButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        public MyButtonRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control.Background != null && e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var buttonBackgroundColor = e.NewElement.BackgroundColor;

                Control.Background = new RippleDrawable(
                    new ColorStateList(
                        new[] { new int[] { } },
                        new[] { new int { } })
                , new ColorDrawable(buttonBackgroundColor.ToAndroid()), null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does my suggested solution answers your question?